# How to import unmanaged dependencies into code

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use sbt to pull down an existing github project and then (obviously) use it in my code. My abbreviated `build.sbt` is shown below:

```
lazy val myProjInGit = RootProject(
  uri("git://github.com/me/sheet-ref.git#master"))

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(myProjInGit)
  .settings(
    name := "MainProj",
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( /*other stuff... */)
```

This is probably a basic one, but how should I then be importing this into code? Could I use, say, `import myProjInGit.SampleObject.sampleFunction` in my `Main.scala`? I can see a disconcerting lack of info on SO about this topic so I'm not sure that I'm not barking up completely the wrong tree. Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: some further details here. The project I am trying to import is just a library, so it only contains a `package object`. To try to debug things a little, I'm trying to import it as a `ProjectRef`, rather than a `RootProject`. I've discovered the `projects` sbt command, and if I run it on the project I'm trying to import (not the main one), it gives me:

```
sbt:SheetRef> projects
[info] In file:/data/va-projects/sheet-ref/
[info]   * SheetRef
```

So... it seems that external project is called SheetRef. If I try to import SheetRef using

```
lazy val sheetRef = ProjectRef(
  uri("git://github.com/me/sheet-ref.git#master"), "SheetRef")
```

then I get an sbt error:

```
[error] No project 'SheetRef' in 'git://github.com/me/sheet-r
ef.git#master'.
[error] Valid project IDs: root
```

Which feels unintuitive. I can import it as root, but then I seem to be unable to access it from my code - if it requires an import statement, it's not obvious to me what it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency has to be an SBT project, so SBT knows how to build it. If it is, then yes, you access it just like any other dependency in your code, because it's added to the classpath (after being built) just like any other dependency.

> Which feels unintuitive. I can import it as root, but then I seem to be unable to access it from my code - if it requires an import statement, it's not obvious to me what it should be.

The thing is, it doesn't matter how you add the dependency; it could be a normal library dependency, an unmanaged dependency, a source dependency, etc. Those are SBT concepts, which have no meaning to the  Scala compiler.

So the `import` statement can't depend on project names, jar names or anything like that. In fact, it's the same as if you just put those files into your own project.

Comment: Thanks - just to add a bit of clarity (maybe), it needs to be imported with its package name - so in my case, where the package name was sheetref, this meant import sheetref.SheetRefObj._

Comment: Well, that applies to your own project's code as well (unless you are in the same package you are importing from).

Comment: I've extended the answer a bit to address your edit, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is there someone that made such a thing work? I am trying the same, and somehow manage to get the git project imported but I have no idea how to access the imported scala components.

Comment: yes, I did. In my case the external package name was 'sheetref' - so I had 'package sheetref' at the top of the .scala files in the external package itself - and then I just used import sheetref.SheetRefObj._ in my main package - SheetRefObj being the main object in the sheetref package. Let me know if that's not clear or if it doesn't work and I'll post up a properly detailed answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man, I've been listening to IDEA which told me it cant resolve the import. It works though! Appreciate it.